# Embedded Android for custom device

Tags: embedded, linux, android

I am using a SOC (System on a Chip) attached to some peripherals like camera and screen. Since this is not a very common hardware setup like a Raspberry Pi where there are adapted android builds for, would it be possible to just use a generic kernel and android branch?

Or am I going to have to adapt the HAL and other components of the android stack?

Comment: Is there a generic android kernel that actually supports your device (has all the required drivers, etc)?

Comment: You will need at least some similar hardware to be supported by the OS, and then you might try to port it to yours. There is no such a thing as "generic kernel".

Comment: @user1850479 no currently there is no kernel supporting the specific hardware I am using. I am wondering which parts of the stack would need to be written if I want to use this hardware with android

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you for the comment. By porting do you mean the HAL needs to be adapted or are there other large modifications to be made to the AOSP?

Comment: Why are you bound to Embedded Android? If that's not a hard requirement, look at other embedded Linux versions which may be much easier to port, such as the Yocto project.

Comment: @user_1818839 I have chosen Embedded Android due to the easier development in upper layers